# Setting default & current options in dropdown select menus

Tags: html, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am using a Wordpress function to add a dropdown populated with custom taxonomy entries for filtering posts. The dropdown menu is created and populated correctly, but I can't either set the default (I want this to be 'All lots') or set the current selection when user chooses an option to filter by.

I have tried adding selected="selected" dynamically as below, but each time the dropdown value defaults to the final option in the select menu. selected="selected" is being added to the correct options - I can see it in firebug.

How do I set the default option to 'All Lots' and how do I display the currently selected option?

```
function custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    if ( $terms ) {
        echo '<form id="sale_selector" method="POST">
            <select id="sale_selection" name="' . $taxonomy . '" class="postform">
                <option value="">All Lots</option>';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    if ( $_POST["online_lot_category"] == $term->slug ){
                        $selected_option = 'selected';
                    } else {
                        $selected_option = '';
                    }
                    echo '<option selected="'.$selected_option.'" value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                }
            echo '</select>
            <input class="filter_button" type="submit" value="OK">
        </form>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that "the currently selected option" is the option specified in $_POST["online_lot_category"] - and if this isn't set, then the default is "All Lots"

When you want to select an option in a dropdown menu, you only have to write

```
<option value="somevalue" selected>text</option>
```

So regardless of whether you type

```
<option value="somevalue" selected="">text</option>
```

or

```
<option value="somevalue" selected="selected">text</option>
```

the browser will interpret the option as being selected.  So, instead, you should use this:

```
...
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( $_POST["online_lot_category"] == $term->slug ){
        $selected_option = ' selected';
    } else {
        $selected_option = '';
    }
    echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '"' . $selected_option . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help